# Memory cache dependencies

Tags: asp.net-core, caching

I'm trying to understand the [Cache dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory#cache-dependencies) example, but some of it is eluding me.

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
_cache.Set(CacheKeys.DependentCTS, cts);

using (var entry = _cache.CreateEntry(CacheKeys.Parent))
{
    // expire this entry if the dependant entry expires.
    entry.Value = DateTime.Now;
    entry.RegisterPostEvictionCallback(DependentEvictionCallback, this);

    _cache.Set(CacheKeys.Child,
        DateTime.Now,
        new CancellationChangeToken(cts.Token));
}
```

`CancellationTokenSource` allows evicting multiple cache entries as a group.  But what's the point of the `using` block in this example?  I downloaded the sample project and replaced the `using` block with the following:

```
_cache.Set( CacheKeys.Parent, DateTime.Now, new CancellationChangeToken( cts.Token ) );
_cache.Set( CacheKeys.Child, DateTime.Now, new CancellationChangeToken( cts.Token ) );
```

While my two lines are simpler, they seem to have the same effect as the `using` block.  The doc says:

> With the `using` pattern in the code above, cache entries created inside the `using` block will inherit triggers and expiration settings.

What does "triggers and expiration settings" refer to here?

I must add dependent cache entries in my application, but they must be added at separate times.  Therefore I can't take the approach shown in the example's `using` block since it requires both entries be added at the same time, right?  What functionality am I missing out on by instead taking the approach shown above in my two lines of code?

Finally, shouldn't `Dispose` be called on `CancellationTokenSource` after the `Cancel` call?  The sample doesn't do that.

Comment: Related Github question, currently without an answer: [Are CancellationTokenSources triggered when invalidated from cache?](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/12828)

Comment: Linking your other related question: [Cache entry whose removal depends on another entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66131398/cache-entry-whose-removal-depends-on-another-entry)